# docker: how to get the code inside the container

Tags: docker

I was reading few articles on how to get code inside docker container.

I found `"In short, for production use ADD/COPY method, for the development use docker volume feature"`

What i understand form the above

1) We will build an image with the code inside it for production. i.e in the production server i have to pull the image and run it. No need to worry about the code files because everything is packed in the image.

2) While developing use volumes to share the folder.

My question is: wheneve i do a change, i will build an image on development server and pull and run that image in the production server.

Assuming my image Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM some-os  -- 375Mb
COPY codefolder /root/  --25MB
```

When i put updated codefolder the image is different from previous.

Most of the times in some-os there are no changes. So codefolder only changes

So everytime (after the first time) i pull the modified image how much MB Is downloaded 400MB or 25 MB

Comment: Not related to the question really, but where do they recommend using volumes in development and ADD/COPY in prod? In my view the best thing with Docker is that you run the same code in dev, test and prod, so I would not give up on that for a somewhat faster local build!

Comment: It looking logical to use volumes during development, because i can use my host editor to modify the code.

Comment: You can do that without volumes as well, you just need to rebuild the docker image after each change. That takes a second or two, so it is marginally slower. Your choice!

Comment: So its first 2s for build docker image and then whatever it usually takes to run the code within the container. Thats fine. FOr that i have to see that my project code also lies where Dockerfile is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the new layer is downloaded after the first time: 25M.

Comment: Great.Also what is the recommended method for getting code inside a docker

Comment: Similar to git is there a place i can put private docker images and pull them from anywhere

Comment: I would use COPY, see https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy.

Comment: There are many places where you can have private docker images, including the docker hub and most cloud vendors. However, it is not free, at least not after the first few images. If you want a private repo you will normally have to pay as far as I know.

Comment: thnks for that info. I have build locally and transfer the image